# Validation required in question preview screen in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, android-app, validation

**What is there to preview without entering any details?** There must be some validations before allowing to preview questions like "title is required", "tags are required", "body must contains >300 characters", etc.

One great thing to check is: such validations are already implemented in Answer section but not here yet.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually did this on purpose since you used to not be able to view the preview screen if the question wasn't postable for any reason, including automatic quality checks and not having any tags. This was a not friendly user experience since you can hit "preview" as many times as you want before actually submitting the question and having those checks work, so we removed it.

You make a good point though, and as of version 0.1.51 coming out soon you won't be able to preview a question without having at least a title and some body text.

Comment: Agree with you but as I and you mentioned there should be some details entered for previewing question, like as you said at least a title.

Comment: Have I really made good point? Shouldn't I get up vote? ;)

Comment: @PareshMayani: Shouldn't your answer? (+1 to both from me ;)